# Creating a web app on django with phone calls functionality

Tags: django, asterisk, sip, voip, freeswitch

So basically i'm developing a piece of software that will allow user to call any number he wants right from the website. So i need some help in choosing the correct  **platform** or **semi cheap service** to use. I guess i need a solution with **open API** because i want to make a db entry (want to record duration and date) for every call made from website.

I've started research and stumbled upon couple of open source solutions: [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) and [FreeSWITCH](https://freeswitch.org/). Trying them out right now, but i still have poor understanding of how SIP works. If it will be a softphone will the user have need to install it on their pc or there are server solutions

Comment: I think you cannot integrate the calls into django anyway, because the call will last longer than the web request. So you need some daemon and communication in between (AMPQ, redis, or some other messaging/queuing system).

Comment: @allo, what if there will be javascript connecting to websocket, and there will be a python/Tornado like framework on top of Asterisk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution that works with any SIP server is to use PJSUA Python bindings and to implement in Python a basic softphone. Thus your web application will be seen by the SIP server just as a regular soft phone and the server configuration is much easier.

Comment: thanks, i look more closely into that. Will write again after i finished.